# Is deduplication possible?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

I never tried it but on closed questions I have a button with which I can vote to reopen it.

What about questions marked as duplicate that I (and possibly others) am convinced is not a duplicate of the linked question for whatever reasons? I never saw a "Vote for deduplicate" button or something like this. So how is the process to unduplicate a question?

Comment: BTW, you need 3,000 reputation to be able to vote to reopen posts, including duplicates (except for your own posts).

Comment: @Mithrandir Good point. Edited my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes.

In exactly the same way as for any other kind of closed question: **click the reopen button**. (Users with less than [250 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) won't see this button at all; users like you with between 250 and 3000 reputation will see it only on their own closed questions; and users with at least [3000 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) will see it on every closed question.)

Random example chosen from among recent questions on the main site (click for full-size version):

[image: screenshot of dupe]

In some ways, the system treats duplicate questions differently from other closed questions. This isn't one of them.

Comment: Sometimes its too easy. :-)